# Change User location(home variable) in Egit (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I use Eclipse Indigo and Windows 7 and plugin egit/jgit for Eclipse.

How to change user location in egit? I should do it, because it contains special characters, which doesn't understand egit. I want "C:\git\home\.gitconfig" instead "C:\Users\Кирилл\.gitconfig". How can I do it? When I press "Open" nothing happens.

And in the next Tab "Repository setting" I don't change anything too.

Comment: oh, I solved this. Just set HOME in Environment variables. Sorry. But I still don't edit tab "Repository setting" and don't delete any repository.

Comment: If you've found a solution, you can write it as an answer and even accept it as _the_ answer. (It just makes it easier to read, than a comment.) Well done on coming back to answer it, though!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add an environment variable:
This is how i did it on windows 7

- Click start button.

  1. Right click "Computer"
  2. Click "Properties"
  3. Click "Advanced System Settings"
  4. "Environment variables" in "Advanced" tab.
  5. Click the "New" button to create a new variable under user variables pane.
  6. Enter "HOME" in the name field
  7. Enter "%USERPROFILE%" or some other path in the value field. (HOME should point to your home directory e.g. C:\Users\Tom. Ensure correct case! E.g. C:\users instead of C:\Users may cause problems!)
  8. Click OK, and OK again. You have just added the Home directory on Windows.

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg I installed Eclipse in D: on my system should I set HOME as you said or should I set to some thing different like D drive

Comment: Where you installed Eclipse does not make a difference, you can set your HOME variable to ane xisting folder, e.g. "C:\Users\Tom"

Comment: Uggg.  Inherited from the *nix version and convention I assume, but seems silly to force users to keep their git config in their main user folder (this is a comment on egit, not on this answer).

Comment: I had to restart Eclipse before the settings would take effect.

Comment: I had to File->Exit Eclipse as opposed to File->Restart for the environment variable to be reread.

Answer (score 2):

Git reads the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable to find the users git config (see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) but unfortunately JGit doesn't look at it.

I've raised a bug here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430194

please log in to the Eclipse Bugzilla and vote for it.