# Git config alias doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, msysgit

I used command:

```
git config --global alias.st status
```

to add my first alias as suggested by post - [How do I alias commands in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git)

Then, I found it being added to config file at:

> C:\Users\damodar.bashyal\.gitconfig

So, i added bunch of aliases directly on the config file and all worked perfectly until today when I had to restart my computer after installing MYOB software.

When i tried to use alias none worked. So, i added another alias using above command, but the file didn't get updated but new alias worked fine.

So after struggling for a while found a command at [ [Where does git config --global get written to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to) ] to look for the config file:

```
git config --global --edit
```

To my surprise, it was showing different location with new git alias added in it.

```
.gitconfig(~) - VIM

[gui]
   recentrepo = C:/_projects/example.com/trunk/bitbucket
[user]
   name = damu
[alias]
   st = status
```

Is there a way to change back path to previous .gitconfig file?

I am using windows 7 and msysgit.

```
c:\>echo %HOME%
%HOME%

c:\>set HOME
HOMEDRIVE=U:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\agsbs\UserShares\Damodar.Bashyal

c:\>echo %HOME%
%HOME%
```

**UPDATE:**
followed this post [ [Change User location(home variable) in Egit (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989847/change-user-locationhome-variable-in-egit-eclipse) ] to set missing HOME environment variable and now i am getting this:

```
c:\>set HOME
HOME=C:\Users\damodar.bashyal
HOMEDRIVE=U:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\agsbs\UserShares\Damodar.Bashyal
```

That also fixed my issue. YAY!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what your `HOME` references:

```
echo %HOME%
# or
set HOME
```

`git config --global` will reference the `HOME` path (unless you would [use the --file option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1475346/6309)).
HOME isn't defined by default on Windows, but it is set by the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/git-cmd.bat#L9-L10) script included with msysgit.

```
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC this is what I got: {see above}

Comment: @DamodarBashyal I confirm: `HOME` isn't defined. Execute the `git-cmd.bat` and repeat those commands: you should see `HOME` defined here.