# Meteor: Error while cloning repo from Github

Tags: git, github, meteor

I am facing problems in installing [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/).

I'm currently going to start working on [Telescope Project](http://demo.telesc.pe/) which is hosted [here](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope).

I have downloaded the Telescope into `D:\Meteor\Telescope`, and installed Meteorite using `npm install -g meteorite` in command prompt.

But when I rum meteorite using `mrt` command I get following errors:

```
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Installing Meteor

  branch: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git#master

Installing smart packages

C:\Users\Snowflax\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteorite\lib\sources\git.js:108
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url;
                                                   ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
```

What is going wrong here? I have `Meteor Preview 0.4.2` already installed on my Windows 7 System. 
Is there any cross-platform issues? Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message comes from [meteorite `lib/sources/git.js`](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/sources/git.js#L103-L114):

```
GitSource.prototype._clone = function(fn) {
  var self = this;
  if (!fs.existsSync(this.sourcePath)) {
    exec('git clone ' + self.url + ' ' + this.sourcePath, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (err)
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url;
      fn();
    });
  } else {
    fn();
  }
};
```

You need to add to the exception message the `this.sourcePath` value, and from there, repeat the `git clone` command manually (in your own `git-cmd` DOS session) in order to see why it fails.

Comment: I have done what you've said, and `this.SourcePath` now gives `undefined`. What could be a problem here?

Comment: @SohelKhalifa it is a configuration issue: meteorite should know where to clone this repo: `this.sourcePath` should be defined, I suppose through https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/sources/git.js#L28-L30, which comes from https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/sources/git.js#L14, defined at https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/meteorite.js#L109-L112... so, is it possible you haven't defined environment variable `HOME`? (not defined by default in Windows)

Comment: @VonC.. yeah there is no any Env. variable defined `HOME` in my system. can you please tell what `HOME` variable contains? I think `USERPROFILE` is also same as `HOME`. But these is no `USERPROFILE` variable either.

Comment: @SohelKhalifa `HOME` can point to any directory of your choice. If you are using git in a `git-cmd.bat` session, it is defined for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13153000/6309. In any case, make sure to execute your `mtr` command in a session where `HOME` is defined (type `set HOME` in your DOS session to see if a value is displayed).

Answer (score 1):

I finally could fix the problem, by uninstalling Meteor and meteorite and installing npm
here's the trick:

First remove meteor

- $ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/meteor (path depending on the distribution)
- $ sudo rm -rf ~/.meteor ~/.meteorite ~/.meteorsession
- $ sudo mrt uninstall
- $ sudo mrt uninstall --system

make sure to have the right permissions:

$ sudo chown -R 'whoami' ~/.npm

Then install again:
download and install node from here: 
http: //nodejs.org/download/

$ curl https://install.meteor.com | sh

$ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite

in last resource there is a workaround, before i could fix the issue i was force to clone manually from Github, not the nicest approach but i will work

1) 
$ mrt add 'package-you-want-to-install'

2)
then copy the link of the git repository i.e.:(https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git)

3)
navigate to packages directory
$ cd packages

4)
then clone the package manually
$ git clone https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git